# What is the meaning of 'It’s strange how dreams get under your skin and give your heart a test for what’s real and what’s imaginary'?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 'It’s strange how dreams get under your skin and give your heart a test for what’s real and what’s imaginary'?
Does get under your skin mean making you very annoyed or upset?

How to understand the sentence?

Comment: "Get under your skin" doesn't mean _annoyed_ here. It means _persist_, or _become an ineluctable part of one_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant What is the meaning that the singer, Jason Mraz, wants to express by saying this sentence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for an interpretation of song lyrics, which is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @Robusto Sorry I don't know this is song lyrics, I just found it as a quote from Jason Mraz. If it is song lyrics, can you tell me the name of the Song? Thanks.

Comment: If there is a particular word or usage in the sentence that you don't understand, you should tell us what it is by editing your question. If you don't, your question may be voted closed.

Comment: @ Robusto I vote not to close this question.  The person has an honest desire to learn something about English which is within the scope of this site.  @ PE Dant, it's quite obvious that 'getting under the skin' is what is troubling him.

Answer (score 1):

Jason Mraz is trying to express that dreams "persist" or "stick with you" and can confuse your mind and/or emotions with what's real and what's not.

"Getting under your skin" can also mean "to annoy", but in this case, it means the former.

Answer (score 0):

In simple English: 'It’s strange how dreams get under your skin and give your heart a test for what’s real and what’s imaginary' means "It's strange how dreams can you make you think about them a lot and change your beliefs about what is real and what is imaginary".  Here 'give your heart a test' is not very common English and probably means 'change your belief' but that's not 100% certain.  Here 'get under your skin' means make you think about it a lot.  Often a certain member of the opposite sex gets under one's skin.

Comment: You see now why "LitCrit" or interpretation are off topic here. The interpretation of a metaphor used by one obscure sensitive singer songwriter or the other, such as "give your heart a test", is entirely _subjective_. There's a good post on the subject **[here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective)**

Comment: @PE Dant, instead of making up excuses to not help the learner why not just help the learner when they ask? Even if  "Give your heart a test" is hard to interpret we should nevertheless make our best effort to explain to someone what it means or give them any information we can.  This site makes far too many excuses to not answer questions.

Comment: @bob - I'm all for helping the learner, but if we are too zealous to help we just become another message board. There are a few problems with this question, the foremost being that it doesn't show any research effort, and it's asking to interpret a song lyric. Part of helping the learner is helping them learn to ask questions that are [sufficiently detailed](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439), [properly cited](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084), and [well-suited for this site](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236).

Comment: P.S. A good discussion about lyric questions can be found [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/why-only-some-questions-asking-lyrics-meaning-are-off-topic-and-not-all)